# Selenium IDE doesn't input text into input field

Tags: selenium, xpath, input, selenium-ide

I am trying to test a registration form in Selenium IDE which should input text values into input fields with the `type` command.

As it can be seen from the picture, the text fields are not recognized as filled and therefore the send button is not available.

How can this be fixed?

I have also tried using `click`, `clickAt`, `focus` commands before `type`, but that also didn't work.

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="selenium.base" href="http://localhost:8090/" />
  <title>registr</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">registr</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>/registration</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input</td>
        <td>vvv</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input</td>
        <td>vvv@mail.ru</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input</td>
        <td>12345</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/input</td>
        <td>12345</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>name=nextStep</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input</td>
        <td>vvv</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input</td>
        <td>vvv</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input</td>
        <td>vvv</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/input</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[3]</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[3]</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[36]</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>xpath=//body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input</td>
        <td>Los-Angeles</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code of this form. Did you try to add a little pause (just to debug) before the validation attempt?

Comment: @Y-BCause I've tried debugging it step by step, but that didn't help

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was talking about the HTML code of the SUT, not your Selenium IDE script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had an Eurêka! moment. I would suggest you to use the `sendKeys` function instead of the `type` function. The `sendKeys` function simulates the Keyboard Keypress Event, which may be required by this form.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it! Thanks!